# Como obtener y utilizar datos de un archivo Json

Tags: java, json, ionic, typescript, npm

estoy haciendo una aplicación con ionic, en la app tengo un calendario en donde se muestran unos eventos, los eventos los creo con typeScript, pero lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que a partir de un documento json pueda obtener los datos del evento y así no tener que hacer los eventos de manera estática.

html:

```
<ion-calendar calendar lang="es" [events]="currentEvents"></ion-calendar>
```

documento TypeScript:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  currentEvents
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.currentEvents = [
      {
        year: 2018,
        month: 7,
        date: 25
      },
      {
        year: 2018,
        month: 7,
        date: 26
      }
    ];
   
  }

}
```

currentsEvents son los eventos que creo en el constructor, pero quisiera que los datos year, month y date, los pueda llenar con los datos de un json.
alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo?
gracias.

[image: asi se ve la app]

así se ve la app

Comment: Por supuesto, hay librerías que te permiten leer un String en formato JSON, probablemente algunas que lo hagan desde un fichero. De hecho, Android ya incorpora una en la plataforma (aunque podrías usar otra). En todo caso escoge una librería, intenta usarla y si tienes problemas haz una pregunta **específica**. Revisa [help], [faq] y [ask] para recordar el tipo de preguntas que se esperan en este sitio.

Comment: Tendrías que hacer una petición http com httpClient (get, post...) y después trabajar con ambos datos con un foreach por ejemplo

Comment: En el documento TypeScript puedo recorrer el archivo json con un foreach?